# Object of type 'X' cannot be converted to type 'X'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

here is my code : 
(IIS Express, ASP.NET MVC5,debugging)

class:

```
public class DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP : BaseEntityDms
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataMember]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? SUBJECT_ID { get; set; }
}
```

client:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = "Form is not valid! Please correct it and try again." });
            }
            IGenericRepository _repository = new Dms.WcfService.GenericRepositoryService();
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string prm = serializer.Serialize(entity);
            var result = _repository.Add(prm, entity.GetType().FullName);
            DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP addedDocumentTypeGroup = (DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP)serializer.Deserialize(result, entity.GetType());
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Record = addedDocumentTypeGroup });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

service:

```
    public class GenericRepositoryService : IGenericRepository
{
    public string Add(string entity, string fullClassName)
    {
        object result;
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Dms.Library.dll");
        Type type = assembly.GetType(fullClassName);
        object instance = serializer.Deserialize(entity, type);
        using (DmsUOW uow = new DmsUOW("DB"))
        {
            object rep = GetRepInstance("Dms.Data." + instance.GetType().Name + "_Repository", uow);
            MethodInfo mInfo = rep.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
            result = mInfo.Invoke(rep, new object[] { instance });
            uow.Flush();
            uow.Commit();
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(result);
    }

   private object GetRepInstance(string strFullyQualifiedName, object prm)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Dms.Data.dll");
        return assembly.CreateInstance(strFullyQualifiedName, false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[] { prm }, null, null);
    }
}
```

ADDITIONAL:

Repository:

```
    public class DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP_Repository : RepositoryEf<DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP>
{
    public DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP_Repository(IUnityOfWork UnityOfWork) : base(UnityOfWork) { }

}
```

RepositoryEF:

```
public class RepositoryEf<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected IUnityOfWork uow;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> objectSet;
    protected DbContext context;

    public RepositoryEf(IUnityOfWork UnitOfWork)
    {
        this.uow = UnitOfWork;
        this.context = UnitOfWork.Context;
        this.objectSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {          
        return objectSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

JavaScriptSerializer cannot deserialize entity parameter. I can't watch instance on debug.-> `object instance = serializer.Deserialize(entity, type);`

I get error "Object of type 'X' cannot be converted to type 'X'".

BUT,

if I call from consoleApplication it works fine.

console:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP d = new DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP();
        d.NAME = "Generic2";
        d.SUBJECT_ID = 12;
        GenericRepositoryService service = new GenericRepositoryService();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string prm = serializer.Serialize(d);
        string s = service.Add(prm, d.GetType().FullName);
        var d2 = (DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP)serializer.Deserialize(s, d.GetType());
    }
```

DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP is in Dms.Library.dll. so I check it's version. and I check  "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"
I rebuild carrefully solution. But it not works.
Also I use Newton.Json . But I get same error. (Sorry for my english)

EDIT:
If I try to cast in Service :

```
public string Add(string entity, string fullClassName)
    {
       ...
        object instance = serializer.Deserialize(entity, type);
        var t = (DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP)instance;
        ..
    }
```

I get this error :

[A]Dms.Library.DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP cannot be cast to [B]Dms.Library.DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP. Type A originates from 'Dms.Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Dms.Library.dll'. Type B originates from 'Dms.Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d33982ca\57fe47a5\assembly\dl3\4ae52973\571dcfde_92b5d001\Dms.Library.dll'.

Comment: which statement throws?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh -> result = mInfo.Invoke(rep, new object[] { instance });  I can't watch instance on Quickwatch. Key:instance , Value:Could not evaluate expression

Comment: `instance` is the parameter you're passing to your `ADD` method.Check for the `Type` and make sure you actually pass what you should toyour repository.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I  added Repository classes in my question. I checked but I could not find the solution.

Comment: what `Type` do you get from `assembly.GetType(fullClassName)`?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh  ->  {Name = "DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP" FullName = "Dms.Library.DOCUMENT_TYPE_GROUP"}